# How can I create a subset of the 'most dissimilar' combinations from a set of possible combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have an array of 32 values.

Each element can have one of four integer values:0 to 3

If I wanted to create an array for each possible combinations I would have 4<sup>32</sup> ( approximately 1.84 x 10<sup>19</sup>) arrays - this is overly burdensome to compute.

Is there a straightforward way to pick fewer combinations, say 1 x 10<sup>6</sup>, by picking the 'most dissimilar' combinations?

By 'most dissimilar' I mean avoiding arrays that are different by one (or few) values and picking arrays that have many dissimilar values.

Note that I have no measure of 'dissimilarity' e.g. 0 and 2 are no more dissimilar than 0 and 1.

Also, if there is an area of mathematics that I should be looking at to improve my description please let me know.

Finally, this is a slightly re-worded version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383642/how-can-i-create-a-subset-of-the-most-dissimilar-arrays-from-a-set-of-possible/22384370?noredirect=1#22384370) StackOverflow question - I thought that this question might also be relevant to the mathematics community.

Comment: Is [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) a candidate for your _dissimilarity_?

Comment: @Fei Gao - Yes that seems to be a good match. Thanks.